# Passing Variable Names in Netezza SQL

Tags: variables, netezza

I'm quite new to Netezza. I'm trying to pass a variable into my select statement, but it gives me the following error:

```
42000(27)ERROR:  'declare filter char(7)'
error    ^ found "DECLARE" (at char 1) expecting a keyword
```

I do not know what I am doing incorrectly. I have tried different variations of the code below, but they all end up with the same error.

```
declare @filter char(7);
set @filter = 'A,B,U,F';
begin
Select @filter from TABLE where DATE = "2019-10-31";
end;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you cannot do that.

The long answer is: Netezza sql and Netezza Stored Procedure syntax may look similar but they are not overlapping as much as you may have seen in sqlserver.

You can definitely do what you need by string manipulation of the sql before you submit it to netezza, and another possibility is to create a stored procedure, but be careful with those if you try to run lots of them in parallel.